# Plot big dataset in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have time serie of measurements of temeprature and light:

```
no,DateTime,Temp,Light
1,11/09/2022 00:01:20,18.10,21.27
2,11/09/2022 00:01:30,18.19,41.70
3,11/09/2022 00:01:40,18.36,5.94
```

...
each measurement is taken every 10 seconds and I have ~40 000 of measurements sorted by dates.

Now I would like to plot a line chart displaying that information (only light).

This is what I get so far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("C:/WG/Temp/TimeSeries.csv", sep=',')
df = df.drop(columns=['Temp', 'no'])

plot1 = df.plot(kind = 'scatter', x = 'DateTime', y = 'Light')
plot1.show()
```

But it freezes (probably because of the amount of points). How it is normally handled, chart doesnt have to be very accurate so I would suppose that it can be somehow resampled to have a mean of measurement for example for each minute. Do you have any advice?

EDIT:

Now code looks like that, but x-axis doesnt look nice. How can I draw on x-axis only every n-th value but remain all points on the chart?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) to a lower frequency (here 1 hour):

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])

(df.resample('1h', on='DateTime')
   ['Light'].mean()
   .plot()
 )
```

Comment: ok, I resampled to 5 min. It is drawn but x axis is difficult to read because there are to many dates on it. How can I show only every n-th value on axis but all values on plot area?

Comment: Please refer to [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63218645/lowering-the-x-axis-value-density-for-dates-on-a-seaborn-line-plot)